# grudging letting go of

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have written below a paragraph to a friend:

No mater how long we have studied English and how fluently we can speak English, we can never pass as native speakers. It is true, we can make ourselves understood in most daily
situations.  Nevertheless, we are always at a loss to know the differences in the way of thinking between the native speakers and us.  Whenever we can discern any difference, **don't grudge letting go of our "cherished" accustomed way of thinking and take to thinking in their way.**

I was saying it jokingly or ironically, I'd like to say that our accustomed way of thinking is hard to get rid of as if it were cherished by us and we are unwilling to part with it.
I'm not sure whether "don't grudge letting go of our cherished accustomed way of thinking and take to thinking in their way" is correct or acceptable to the native ear.

Comment: What do you think 'grudge' means as a verb?

Comment: And the Oscar goes to... Sorry, I mean and the question is?

Comment: @JonathanPotter - grudge verb [ T ] (also begrudge) to not want to spend time or money on someone or something, or to not want to give something to someone: _She grudged every hour she spent helping him._ [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grudge)

Comment: I think *begrudge* is more common than *grudge* as a verb (*grudge* is the usual noun).